# Can I connect dual monitors one to vga, other to hdmi?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I am planning to set a dual monitor setup. I am on a laptop with i3 3rd gen 1.8 GHz 3217u, 2GB of Intel graphics 4000 HD, 4gb of ram. So can I connect one monitor to the HDMI port and the other to the VGA port. Is it possible.

Comment: Do you have a dedecated GPU?

Comment: no just the intel 4000 (i have actually connected one monitor before that just worked fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Intel ( http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-031040.htm ) your Graphics chip supports up to three monitors, however you haven't given any further information on your system and intel claims that support for multiple displays needs to be given by 'your computer's configuration' to work. You should particularly check your mainboard's documentation to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Ya i know that but my question is weather i can connect one to hdmi and other to vga and get two different monitors?

Comment: Well if your hardware supports it then yes, in principle you can have multiple monitors on different ports.